# Error: type SugarRecord does not take parameters

Tags: android, sugarorm

I'm getting this error in compile time after I cloned the repo and imported the library folder as a module in my AndroidStudio project (I need to make some changes to the library so I have to clone it)

```
public class UserBean extends SugarRecord<UserBean> implements Bean, Serializable {
    ...
}
```

when I take a look at my SugarRecord I don't see any generic parameter neither

```
public class SugarRecord {

    protected Long id = null;
    ...
}
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out the Generic parameter in SugarRecord is not needed anymore.